# ¿Cómo encontrar un dato y añadirlo a otra columna?

Tags: r

A ver si alguien sabe como hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo un df con letras y números, quiero que si me detecta un numero en concreto me añada dicho numero en otra columna.

Algo así

```
df <- data.frame(c("CASA AV 23","PEPE 34","QWE","AVION NARANJA ROJO VERDE AV 24",
                    "WERRR ER34","AV 25"))

colnames(df)<-c("nombre1")

df[grepl("AV 23",df$nombre1), "Nombre1_numero"]= "23"
df[grepl("AV 24",df$nombre1), "Nombre1_numero"]= "24"
df[grepl("AV 25",df$nombre1), "Nombre1_numero"]= "25"
```

o sea, busca `AV 23`, `24`, `25` en la columna, si lo encuentra pone el numero en otra columna, el resto de datos como `NA`. Como son muchos, para no repetir siempre lo mismo había pensado en algo así

```
df[grepl("AV \\d{2}",df$nombre1), "Nombre1_numero"]= "\\d{2}"
```

pero no se como poner ese "\d{2}" ultimo para que me coloque el numero.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con R base se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
df$Nombre1_numero <- sapply(regmatches(df$nombre1,regexec("AV (\\d{2})",df$nombre1)), function(x) if (length(x)>1) {x[[2]]} else {NA})


df
                         nombre1 Nombre1_numero
1                     CASA AV 23             23
2                        PEPE 34           <NA>
3                            QWE           <NA>
4 AVION NARANJA ROJO VERDE AV 24             24
5                     WERRR ER34           <NA>
6                          AV 25             25
```

- La parte principal es `regmatches(df$nombre1,regexec("AV (\\d{2})",df$nombre1))`, con lo cual obtenemos, en caso de encontrar el patrón, la cadena completa encontrado, por ejemplo `AV 23` y el patrón capturado `(\\d{2})`, es decir el número.
- Por último, con `sapply(..., function(x) if (length(x)>1) {x[[2]]} else {NA})`, no quedamos con el parón capturado o devolvemos `NA` en caso de no haber encontrado nada en la fila.

Algo parecido, aunque más conciso, es usar `str_match()`  del paquete `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_match(df$nombre1, "AV (\\d{2})")[,2]
[1] "23" NA   NA   "24" NA   "25"
```